# django-widget-tweaks error while rendering in Django 2.1

Tags: django, django-2.1, django-widget-tweaks

While trying to use `OSMField` from `django-osm-field` and rending it with with `django-widget-tweaks` I am getting this error:

> ```
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py",
> ```
>
> line 93, in as_widget
>           renderer=self.form.renderer,
>       TypeError: render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'renderer'

However, downgrading from Django **2.1.x** to **2.0.x** it seems to be resolved